# How should i make pattern with parameters in keycloak.security-constraints

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I'm working on an application and for security tokens I used Keycloak. Problem is that I don't know how to secure patterns with parameters.
I runs properly when i used sometring like:

`keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/books/list`

but i want special security on genres so i have additional parameter like ?genre=adults and i tried to do:

`keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/books/list?genre=*`

It doesn't work and I don't know why.